# Unable to select multiple layers and/or use Align tool in Gimp

Tags: gimp

I'm trying to align some layers in Gimp. I cannot select more than 1 layer at a time. The Align tool is also greyed out (presumably because I have only selected one object).

[image]

I have seen some Google results saying that you can't select multiple layers in Gimp. However, [their docs clearly state](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-align.html) that you can shift-click to select multiple layers, or drag a rectangle to select them all.

I am using Gimp 2.10 in Windows 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't select multiple layers in the layers panel in GIMP. It's not possible. In any case, that's not how the Alignment Tool works anyway (*see note below).

You need to use the Alignment Tool <kbd>Q</kbd> to select the objects on the canvas for the alignment options to work. You can use <kbd>Shift</kbd> to select multiple objects, or you can click and drag with the tool to encompass the objects you want to select.

Each object needs to be on its own layer, and each of the layers must be cropped to their content (you can use *Layer > Crop to Content*)

Here's an example showing the tool working. You can see when each object is selected it gets four little square handles.

[image]

*Note: To be honest, the user manual doesn't really describe it well - it's quite poorly worded. Instead maybe check out this rather nice [video tutorial on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=maDlaexrdac&feature=emb_logo) which goes into some depth on how to use the tool.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is a great explanation. I didn't even think to try dragging the tool. I'm not used to the align tool being, well, a *tool*, not a button that you click after selecting layers.

Comment: @ale19 - well the user manual is a bit of a bum steer, so not entirely your fault.